# could redis different language client can mixed use?

Tags: serialization, redis, thrift

as we know apache thrift rpc framework can use different language client store and access,for an instance,
use python client set "1"
use ruby client get "1"
they get the same value

so my question is redis support this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Redis uses a very simple protocol which is independent to language. You can use libraries from different languages and they can work together :)